# Running / killing executable using .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Batch file scripting is brand new to me, so please be patient with me...

In order to run many (*e.g.* 5076) calculations on a windows (10, 64-bit) environment, I use the `.bat` file:

```
gulp.exe < input-1.dat > output-1.out
gulp.exe < input-2.dat > output-2.out
gulp.exe < input-3.dat > output-3.out
                 .
                 .
                 .
gulp.exe < input-5076.dat > output-5076.out
```

Unfortunately, some of the calculations will hang (for unknown reasons)...currently, when this occurs, I manually kill the whole batch command...which, means I have to keep an eye on how the calculations are progressing and cannot simply leave them running (e.g. overnight)

Thus, I am looking for a way of automatically killing the gulp.exe executable if it has been running for 30mins, but in a way that will mean the next calculation in my list still runs.
*i.e. if calculation 2 hangs, kill it and run calculation 3*

A search [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7)[, 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284101/batch-script-to-call-executable-and-exit-if-it-hangs)]
indicates that `taskkill` might be the command I am looking for, but am a little confused as to whether it kills the .bat script or the executable and how to apply it to more than 1 calculation in the list.

Thus, I would really appreciate some pointers...
Thanks

Comment: Since one task is executed after the other, there should only be one process called `gulp.exe`, so `taskkill /IM gulp.exe` should work (add `/F` to force killing; perhaps add `/FI "status ne running"` if the hangs are reflected by a status `not responding`); I am not sure if you might need to prepend every `gulp` call with `start "" /WAIT`...

Answer (score 1):

The calculations consume CPU time so you can analyze it in 1 second samples with built-in [typeperf](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490960.aspx), assuming there can only be one GULP process running at a time.

```dos
@echo off

set INTERVAL=1
set CPUTHRESHOLD=0.1

call :runGulp "input-1.dat" "output-1.out"
call :runGulp "input-2.dat" "output-2.out"
call :runGulp "input-3.dat" "output-3.out"

pause
exit /b

:runGulp
    start /b gulp <"%~1" >"%~2"
    :wait
        for /f "delims=, tokens=2 skip=2" %%a in ('
            typeperf "\Process(GULP)\%% Processor Time" -si %INTERVAL% -sc 1
        ') do (
            if %%~a GEQ %CPUTHRESHOLD% goto wait
            if %%~a==-1 exit /b
        )
    taskkill /f /im gulp.exe
    exit /b
```

Comment: hi @wOxxOm, thanks for your response to my question. Unfortunately, I have tried the code you provided, with a couple of example files, but am simply getting the error ' system cannot find the batch label specified - runGulp'...because I thought the call keyword is trying to open a separate batch file, I have a .bat file in the same folder called 'runGulp.bat' which is of the same structure as my original file...I don't really understand, so I would be extremely grateful if you could advise.

Comment: There was a typo, I've fixed it.

Comment: ok, the fix has worked (I think - the script/calculations now run at least). But, and I am really sorry about this, I am confused...am I right in thinking: the typeperf function looks at the processor time - storing the value in a; that it takes just 1 sample (-sc 1) [or is it that one sample is taken at 1 second intervals]. Also, with a cputhreshold of 0.1, isn't 'a' always going to be greater than the threshold? how does/or why would a ever equal -1? apologies if these are stupid questions...thanks

Comment: You can test it yourself: launch some long-running gulp command in one window and in another Command Prompt window run `typeperf "\Process(GULP)\%% Processor Time" -si 1 -sc 1`. As for the command line switches you can always run `typeperf /?` to see the description.

Comment: when I try and test it like you say, I simply get the message 'error: no valid counters' and a note that tells me I need to be a member of the local performance log users group or I need to execute the command from an elevated command prompt. I have no idea what these mean...wrt to the former, I am an admin and only user on the laptop I am using; wrt to the latter, how do I do so?